# Why have 1 extra level for servlet config in web.xml?

Tags: java, xml, servlets

The servlet config looks like this -

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>smart</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>SuperSmart</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>smart</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/dumb</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Its said that all these aliases are for security. I get that. But why do we have to map it to a servlet-name first and then to the servlet-class ? Why can't the server find the url pattern and directly map it to the servlet-class ?

Comment: It's just a data normalization.

Answer (score 1):

The aim of this is that the servlet could be referenced by more than one mapping, so you can map one servlet to **more than one** url (or pattern) and not just one.

Answer (score 0):

The name is sort of like and "ID" that tells the container which `<servlet>` part goes with which `<servlet-mapping>` part (as well as ties it to other parts of the XML config in container specific XML files)

You can have multiple url patterns tied to the same servlet name.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it seems ugly, but it's an attempt to keep the servlet config [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), as `servlet-name` can be used in [filter-mappings](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1039330) as well as servlet-mappings.

In servlet spec 3.0 you can annotate the servlets themselves which is neater.

Answer (score 0):

It was designed that way to allow other components, such as filters, can access it. Filters can either be associated with a Servlet by using the `<servlet-name>` style:

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Image Filter</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>ImageServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```